# Force close Message app

Tags: ios, message, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

How can I force the Message app to close on a jailbroken device?

I have deleted messages from the database, but the phone numbers still appear; I think it's  because the Message app is still running and has the information cached.

Comment: Looking at your other questions, I'm assuming this app is not only installed on a jailbroken device, but installed outside the normal sandbox area, e.g. in `/Applications`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
system("/usr/bin/killall MobileSMS");
```

Comment: it return 256,what does this mean?

Comment: I believe that return code `256` just means that the MobileSMS process was not running, when you tried to kill it.  It isn't **always** running.  If you reboot the phone, it won't be running until you use the app the first time.  If you make sure to run the app once, and try it again, you should get return code `0`, which is success.  Also, I'd recommend using the full, absolute path `/usr/bin/killall` with `system()`.

Comment: It's not a typo to not use the leading slash.  It's just generally safer to use absolute paths with the `system()` command.  It should still function with `usr/bin/killall`, though.